# Symfony2 logged in but not authenticated in profiler

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm making an authentication system on Symfony 2.6.
The registration process works. When I try to login, I'm logged in and I have the "ROLE_USER", but the profiler says I'm not authenticated. I don't understand what's happening.
Here is the User entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="baseuser")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("email", message="error.user.email.taken")
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=70, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=128)
 * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=64)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $picture;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
private $zipcode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthdate", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $birthdate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="occupation", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $occupation;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="about", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $about;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=15, unique=true)
 */
private $token;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="integer")
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;

public function __construct()
{
    $datetime = new \DateTime();
    $this->createdAt = $datetime;
    $this->updatedAt = $datetime;
    $this->token     = base_convert(time(), 10, 36).\AppBundle\Library\StringHelper::randomString(5, "lower");
    $this->salt      = \AppBundle\Library\StringHelper::randomString();
    $this->isActive  = true;
    $this->roles     = 1;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/**
* Return the roles
*
*/
public function getRoles() {
    switch ($this->roles) {
        case 1:
            $role =  'ROLE_USER';
            break;

        case 2:
            $role =  'ROLE_ADMIN';
            break;

        case 3:
            $role =  'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN';
            break;

        default:
            $role = 'ROLE_USER';
            break;
    }

    return array($role);
}

/**
* Set the roles
*
* @param $roles
*/
public function setRoles($roles) {
    $this->roles = $roles;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::serialize()
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password
    ));
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
}
```

And here is my security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
         AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost:      15

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: email }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~
            logout: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I don't know what the problem is, any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.
First, you need a username, and it must not be blank. So I changed my method getUsername() so it returns the email address.
Then, I changed my security.yml to look like this :

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 13

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        users:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: email }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~
            logout: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 6):

Class User has to implement EquatableInterface and implement method as follows:

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->id === $user->getId();
}
```

Comment: I never needed this method before but I ran into this issue when starting a new S3.3 project.  I should point out that the code https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.php specifically warns against using the id as a checker and indeed there is no UserInterface::getId() method defined.  Consider using: return $this->username === $user->getUsername();  Still wish I understood why I did not need this interface before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms and this was because I was trying a user with no ROLE.

The profiler seems to consider a user authenticated if he have at least one role.

Here is what it is said in the profiler detail:

> User is not authenticated probably because they have no roles.

Even if he have `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and/or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` the pseudo roles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you removed the `dev` firewall from your `security.yml`:

```
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
```

Make sure you insert before any other firewalls...

See the original [**security.yml**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/config/security.yml)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added back the dev firewall in my security.yml. Unfortunately, the problem is still there. The profiler says :
No token
See this pic : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10127700/S%C3%A9lection_004.png

Comment: I assume you did the `cache:clear` after putting the `dev` in place?

Comment: I did yes. I don't understand what is that token problem

Comment: Which exact version of `SF2` are you using?

Comment: Symfony version 2.6.4 - app/dev/debug